# How to display content of a link in a tooltip on hover

Tags: javascript

I need to display the content returned from a link in a tooltip on hovering over that link.

I know about the some jquery plugins, which displays inline content, But didn't come across any plugin which satisfy my requirement.

If any one know any tooltip plugin, which loads the content from a link and displays it on hover, please help me.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: http://groups.drupal.org/node/233653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Beauty Tips](http://drupal.org/project/beautytips) is a drupal module and a jQuery plugin that will allow you to display content tooltip style via hover, click or a range of other events.

There is to my knowledge not built in support for loading content from different placed, but this is near trivial with the power of jQuery AJAX APIs.

Comment: Does this module have problem with Mozilla Firefox..? For me its crashing in Firefox, whereas working fine with other browser.